# Enable "Post Formats" Just For a "Custom Post Type" And Not Others In WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, post-format

I've been struggling with Post Formats and CPTs in WordPress and after many hours, I decided to create some CPTs and enable Post Formats for them.

The problem is, when I enable Post Formats, they become available for all of the post types; and I want to have them just for some of the CPTs and not other ones.

*Assume I have three CPTs called "**article**", "**webinar**" and "**tutorial**" . I want to enable Post Formats just for "**webinar**".*

What I've done is to create a plugin and enable Post Formats with:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array( 'audio', 'image', 'video', 'gallery' ));
```

after that, I tried to enable them for CPT which is called **medya**:

```
add_post_type_support( 'medya', 'post-formats');
```

and then, I tried to disable them for defalut "post" post type.

```
remove_theme_support( 'post', 'post-formats');
```

But it doesn't work and Post Formats are enabled for both.
Any suggestions?

Comment: This is a WordPress related question and should go to https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: How can I? @VladOlaru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answered**

I found the answer [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_meta_box).

```
function remove_pf() {
    remove_meta_box( 'formatdiv','post','normal' );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_pf' );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add in functions.php

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'mjt_remove_formats', 100);
function mjt_remove_formats()
{
   remove_theme_support('post-formats' , array( 'post' ));
}
```

Comment: My problem isn't enabling Post Formats for new CPTs; I want to disable them for default WordPress posts.

Comment: I think a CPT is also a post and when something is disabled for 'post', it will be disabled for CPTs too. Am I right?

Comment: Thanks for your response @Madhavi. I found the answer.